# Discord selfbot call users

Tags: discord.py, command

So im working on a discord seflbot using python and i wanna make an command which will spam call an dm but i use the default discord.py so i cannot do that. Can anyone help me out with an code example for that using discum or discord.py-self? (Will give credits even tho i will recode it myself after i learn how i can make the spam caller)

I tried to make it hop on a vc in dms the same way a bot would in a guild's channel which didn't work. I tried to check online but i couldnt find what i was looking for

Comment: Selfbots aren't allowed in discord's TOS. Also, you haven't provided any code at all whatsoever.